# img src not connecting to image path

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, macos

[image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt2t0.png)frustrating question to say the least. I'm simply trying to add an image to a site. img src is not getting the image. I tested the path as a background-image and it links fine. Whenever I copy over that same exact path to the img tag is doesn't find it. I even copied the exact full path of the image and nothing.

heres the html :

```
    <div class='img_work1'>
                    <img src=../img/screenshotonce.png/>
                    <div class='caption'>
                        <h2>Website</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and heres the css for the background image (the part that works)

```
   .img_work1{
height:300px;
position:relative;
margin-top:2em;
margin-bottom:15%;
background-image:url('../img/screenshotonce.png');
```

I added both links just to show that the img src link is exactly the same as the background image path, but doesn't show up.

Comment: Could be issue of path. Can you post your `<img>` tag and css containing `background-image` ?

Comment: Some code would be useful.

Comment: added more details for you all to see ! let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Can you share your file structure ?

Answer (score 1):

have you set the image permissions? if not set up first, for example if you use linux os then you can type

> chmod 777 /pathimage/nameimage.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is a typo, but interesting enough, so I'll give an answer:

In HTML, contrary to XHTML and other XML languages, a void element (a.k.a self-closing) should not have a `/` before the last `>`.

And you felt in one of the very rare cases where it matters.

Because HTML is also very permissive, it allows you to not wrap your attributes' values inside `"`.

But then when you combine both these errors, your attribute is not parsed as you would like:

`<img src=abc.xyz/>` will set the `src` attribute to `"abc.xyz/"`, not to `"abc.xyz"`.

```js
console.log(i.src);
```

```html
<img id="i" src=abc.xyz/>
```

For the browser, this means that *"abc.xyz"* points to a directory, hence your image fails to load.

So you can fix it by either wrapping your `src` attribute inside `"` or by replacing this `/>` with `>` at the end of your tag, or as it should be, both of it:

```
<img src="abc.xyz">
```

---

**[edit]** Since we've got more info on OP's files path.

Also, URLs in css `url()` func are relative to the stylesheet.

> For CSS style sheets, the base URL is that of the style sheet itself, not that of the styled source document.

<sup>from [CSSWG specs on `url()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#relative-urls)</sup>

So if your css file is not in the same directory as your html one, it might have to be different.

Comment: Great to know, thank you for this  . Only thing is it still doesn't fix it, I'll post my image path above

Comment: @Swink and where are placed your css and html files in this path? If it is an external css file, URIs in `url()` are relative to the css file, not to the HTML document

Comment: all my html and css files are placed within the same main folder (portfolio_site in the image)

Answer (score 0):

Is your syntax the following:

1. `<img src="http://localhost/path/to/image">`
2. `<img src="/path/to/image">`

If it is not fix that, then check again. Press <kbd>Ctrl (Command)</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (Inspect Element) and check if any CSS rules are applied to the image. Find any that cause the image to display incorrectly.